# Run multiple Magento 2 versions in windows xampp

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php-7, cli, xampp

I have to work in `Magento 2.1.7` and `Magento 2.2.5` and for that, I need to install a different version of PHP, I have installed multiple xampp with different port no which resolves PHP requirement.

But now to run `Magento CLI` with different PHP version is my problem.

Every time to run older Magento I have to change `Environment variable` in my system. Is there any other workaround for this?

I know windows is not recommended for the Magento 2 development. But I have to use it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to go about it. You just have to use the full path when invoking php in the CLI. So for instance instead of `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` you will use the full path like this `C:\wamp\bin\php\php bin\magento setup:di:compile`

You can further try aliases for your php versions, to make it simpler.

Comment: you are right in case of `wamp` it is working. I have tested it by running a script with by installing `wamp`, but in case of `xampp` it is not. I have tried to use `d:/Projects/New_Xampp/php bin/magento -v` which throws following message  `bash: d:/Projects/New_Xampp/php: Is a directory`